# Get the simple fraction of decimal number c#

Tags: c#, math, fractions

I need to get the simple fraction of a decimal number in c#

**Example:**

```
1 would be 1 /1
16 would be 16 / 1
0.125 would be 1 / 8
.30769231 would be 4/13
```

**The solution i found is this:**

```
Decimal_target= 0.1

In the numerator and denominator for the decimal values i used (Decimal_target*(random number between 1- 10)/random number)

The random number got was 9 so: ((0.1*9)/9)=0.1

Numerator = 0.9
Denominator = 9
```

**But the numerator and denominator needs to be integer numbers...**

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/converting-decimals-fractions.html

Comment: This seems more like a simple math problem whose solution could be found from a quick  internet search than a C# programming question.

Comment: Why are you picking a random number?  Talk us through your logic there...

Comment: I'm coding this process in c#

Comment: Random number has no reason, just pick a random number to do (Decimal_target*(random number between 1- 10)/random number) This would get the actual decimal target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code.  Can get stuck in infinite loop (let OP solve this issue).  I rounded to number of decimal places in input :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] numbers = { "1", "16", "0.125", ".30769231" };

            foreach (string number in numbers)
            {
                int numerator = 1;
                string strNumerator = "";
                int denominator = 1;
                string strDenominator = "";


                Boolean done = false;

                if (!number.Contains("."))
                {
                    strNumerator = number;
                    strDenominator = "1";
                    done = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    int numberDecimalPlaces = number.Substring(number.IndexOf(".")).Length - 1;
                    string tempStr = number;
                    if (number.StartsWith(".")) tempStr = "0" + tempStr;
                    double value = double.Parse(number);

                    while(!done)
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            double newTemp = numerator / (double)denominator;
                            string newTempStr = newTemp.ToString("F" + numberDecimalPlaces.ToString());
                            if (newTempStr == tempStr)
                            {
                                strNumerator = numerator.ToString();
                                strDenominator = denominator.ToString();
                                done = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            denominator++;
                            if (newTemp <= value)
                            {
                                numerator += 1;
                                denominator = numerator + 1;
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine("Results for : '{0}', numerator = '{1}', denominator = '{2}'", number, strNumerator, strDenominator);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```